# Overlapped label below tikz tree node

Tags: tikz-arrows, labels, tikz-trees, overlap

I'm new to latex and I'm using the tikz package to draw a simple binary tree.
I want to put a long question under a node but it's overlapping with the arrows. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset {
    my_circle/.style = {circle, draw= black}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, sibling distance=4cm, level distance = 4cm]
\node [label=below:{I need to put here a long question!}, my_circle]{1}
    child{node[my_circle] {2} edge from parent node[left] {yes}
    }
    child{node [my_circle]{3}
        child{node [my_circle] {6}
        edge from parent node [left] {yes}}
        child {node [my_circle]{7}
         edge from parent node[right] {no}}
    edge from parent node [right] {no}} 
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By doing this I have this result: [image: Overlapping arrows]

What I'm trying to do is to start the arrows after the question: 
[image: Desired result]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! Just `shorten` the respective edges.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\tikzset {
    my_circle/.style = {circle, draw= black}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, sibling distance=4cm, level distance = 4cm]
\node [label=below:{I need to put here a long question!}, my_circle]{1}
    child{node[my_circle] {2} edge from parent[shorten <=0.8cm] node[left] {yes}
    }
    child{node [my_circle]{3}
        child{node [my_circle] {6}
        edge from parent node [left] {yes}}
        child {node [my_circle]{7}
         edge from parent node[right] {no}}
    edge from parent[shorten <=0.8cm] node [right] {no}} 
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd recommend switching to `forest`. With this package you can say things like

```
where level=1{edge={shorten <=6mm}}{},
```

in order to shorten the edges in all edges at that level. And much more. And the syntax is simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
yes/.style={edge label={node[auto,pos=0.7,swap]{yes}}},
no/.style={edge label={node[auto,pos=0.7]{no}}},
where level=1{edge={shorten <=6mm}}{},
for tree={circle,draw,s sep+=2em,l sep+=3em}
[1,label=below:{I need to put here a long question!}
 [2,yes]
 [3,no
  [6,yes]
  [7,no]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the fast answer! I'd like also to ask you what are the advantages of the forest?

Comment: @Max It is just so much more powerful. I added an example, but in this one you cannot really see the advantages. However, if you go to more complicated trees, you will.